# Simple Scheduled Task on SSH

Tags: ssh, console, scheduled-tasks

I'm a complete noob at this whole SSH thing. If someone could write me up some detailed instructions on how to do the following, it would be greatly appreciated!

So, at 2:01 AM and 2:01 PM, I need the server to input "restart" into the console. This will trigger a program I have running to restart and reconnect to another server, which restarts at 2:00 AM & PM. Both servers are currently in EDT time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know `crontab`? You can create there scheduled tasks at any time, for example:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
1 2,14    * * *   user    restart
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. Will the configuration you provided go off every 12 hours at 2?